# Unable to select item in cypress inside a frame

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have managed to log into a laboratory results system but I can't progress any further.  My long term intention is to grab lab results for local incorporation into a medical record.

```
const getIframeBody = () => {
  // get the iframe > document > body
  // and retry until the body element is not empty
  return cy
  .get('frame[id="EclairMainFrame"]')
  .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
  // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
  // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
  // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
  .then(cy.wrap)
}

describe('Medlab Test', () => {
    it('Visits Eclair', () => {
      cy.visit('https://cdr.medlabcentral.co.nz/Eclair/mvc')
      cy.get('.login-field').eq(0).type('userid')
      cy.get('.login-field').eq(1).type('passphrase{enter}')
      cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/Eclair/ClinicalWorkstation.aspx')
      getIframeBody().find('.search-form-form-textbox') 
    })
  })
```

This gets me logged in, but Cypress fails to find the input field to enter the Patient ID.  I see the following error message:

> Timed out retrying after 6000ms: Expected to find element:
> .search-form-form-textbox, but never found it. Queried from element: <body>

The DOM at this point for that input field shows:

```
<input class="search-form-form-textbox Mandatory" id="PatAliasId" name="PatAliasId" type="text" value="" tabindex="4">
```

[image]

I've tried cy.get on the class `cy.get('.search-form-form-textbox')`, on the id `cy.get('#PatAliasId')`, and on class attribute `cy.get('name=["PatAliasId"]')` but all these attempts time out at 6 seconds.

What's the correct syntax for finding a dom element inside a frame?

Comment: Can you post the full DOM above the Patient ID field? Is the field in the Shadow DOM? Is it in an iFrame?

Comment: Yes it's in a frame.  Source is here https://gist.github.com/gchiu/5116e4def0a76c3ed62b5c93d78f7a8a

Comment: Your gist doesn't include the iframe tag.

Comment: Sorry, realised that after I left the house. When I get home.

Comment: Ok, updated the gist, and hopefully all the information is there now.  thanks

Comment: What's the exact error message you get on trying one of those `cy.get()` commands? I'm not seeing anything standing out in the gist.

Comment: I added some more code to get the body of the frame (taken from a cypress blog) and the error message.

Comment: Try like that `cy.get('frame[id="EclairMainFrame"]').then(function ($link) {
            var ifele = $link.contents().find('0.contentDocument.body')}`

Comment: @KrupalVaghasiya feel free to submit a fully formed answer.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To work with frames in Cypress you have to install a cypress plugin with the following command, then you can interact with elements inside the frame

```
npm install -D cypress-iframe
```

Reference URL
[Cypress Frames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe)

If you have done the above already, then load the frame first to find the required element

```
cy.frameLoaded(#frameId)
cy.iframe.find('#PatAliasId').type('abc')
```

Comment: I get an assertion error: Timed out retrying after 6000ms: Expected to find element: iframe, but never found it.

Answer (score 0):

In previous version of cypress, don't have any support for the iFrame. But in latest version cypress provided the support for iFrames.

Do work on cypress , we need to install cypress-iframe by using the below commands.

**npm install -D cypress-iframe**

Use this below code:

```
describe('Medlab Test', () => {
    it('Visits Eclair', () => {
      cy.visit('https://cdr.medlabcentral.co.nz/Eclair/mvc')
      cy.frameLoaded('#frameId')
      cy.iframe.find('#PatAliasId').type('Enter Your Input')
    })
  })
```

Comment: Same error as the other answer.  Also syntax in your answer is wrong.